# Can I load a module only if a condition is verified?

Tags: node.js, express, module, formidable

After this question:

[Formidable and form not multipart but with method post (perhaps an issue of sincronicity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129350/formidable-and-form-not-multipart-but-with-method-post-perhaps-an-issue-of-sinc)

I verified that if I insert a code like this:

```
app.use(function (request, response, cb) {
    var type="form";
    if(request!=undefined && request.headers!=undefined && request.headers['content-type']!=undefined) {
        type=request.headers['content-type'];
        if(type.startsWith("multipart"))
        {
            console.log("Load formidable");
            formidable();
        }
        cb();
});
```

the app print  "load formidable" but request.fields is empty and also the stack trace doesn't report the correct load of formidable!
Someone encountered a similar problem and found a solution?

P.S.: I tried also to externalize this code but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I resolve the problem passing from express to restify!
I will not accept this answer because I would know if the same thing is possible with express but I would tell to future curious how I resolve this problem.